# Insert a node before another node in singly linked list in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, singly-linked-list

I did see this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198508/given-a-node-how-can-i-find-previous-node-in-a-singly-linked-list) [java] and am attempting a similar solution, but the noted thread did not fully answer my question)

I need to work with singly linked lists and want to try and perform an insertBefore() method. I understand that doubly-linked lists have a previous attribute, while singly linked lists do not, so I understand this might be better accomplished using doubly-linked lists, but this was the requirements of the assignment and I'm trying to solve things.

So far below: I've got my Node class setup along with my SinglyLinkedList class. I've also got my insertBefore() method, which is my goal and where I'm getting stuck.

You'll see in my if statement, I'm hoping to compare `node.next.value` to my `targetNode` (note that targetNode is a value) -- why is my node.next.value throwing me the following error? `if node.next.value == targetNode: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'`

```
# this is our node object
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

# this is our singly linked list object
class SinglyLinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insertBefore(self, targetNode, value):
        # create new node
        newNode = Node(value)
        # find target node to insert
        node = self.head
        if node == None:
            print 'There aren\'t any nodes to insert before!'
        else:
            found = None
            # search nodes
            while node:
                if node.next.value == targetNode:
                    found = True
                    print node.value + ' <--this was node before target'
                    beforeInsert = node
                    afterInsert = node.next
                    beforeInsert.next = newNode
                    newNode.next = afterInsert # sets new node's next to target node
                    node = node.next # continues through while loop
                else:
                    node = node.next
            if found != True:
                print 'Your target node of {} was not found in the list!'.format(targetNode)
```

*Please note*: I was able to get this to work for an insertAfter() method (not included in the snippet above), but am struggling to match up the `node.next` with the `targetNode` object.

Comment: Why did someone down vote me for asking this question? What's wrong with my question above and why can't I ask something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I was able to find a solution to my question:

```
    def insertBefore(self, targetValue, value):
    # create new node
    newNode = Node(value)
    # find target node to insert
    node = self.head
    if node == None:
        print 'There aren\'t any nodes to insert before!'
    else:
        found = False
        # search nodes
        while node:
            if node.next == None:
                break
            if node.next.value == targetValue:
                found = True
                newNode.next = node.next
                node.next = newNode
                break
            else:
                node = node.next
        if found != True:
            print 'Your target node of {} was not found in the list!'.format(targetValue)
```

Note, as Jonas pointed out in his comments, the above mentioned solution only works if there are no duplicates in the node list.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest yourself, the problem seems to be that you create a new node using your target node, `node.next == Node(targetNode)` as this will never be true.

I assume that targetNode is a Node object, in which case you should simply use `node.next == targetNode`.

Another problem with your code is that you do not check if the first node is the target node. Thus, you would not be able to insert a node before the head `Node` using the `insertBefore` function.

The following code is a rewrite of your `insertBefore` function which inserts a new node with the specified value before a given node.

```
def insertBefore(self, targetValue, value):
    # create new node
    newNode = Node(value)
    # find target node to insert
    node = self.head
    if node == None:
        print 'There aren\'t any nodes to insert before!'
    else:
        # search nodes
        if node.value == targetValue:
          newNode.next = self.head
          self.head = newNode

        while node.next is not None:
            if node.next.value == targetValue:
                print ">>> ",node.value,' <--this was node before target'
                newNode.next = node.next
                node.next = newNode
                return
            else:
                node = node.next
        print 'Your target node of {} was not found in the list!'.format(targetNode.value)
```

If you want `targetNode` to be the value of the target node, you will need to compare `node.next.value` with `targetNode`. Note that this would insert the value before the first occurrence of the target value. Thus, you might want to turn you list into a set instead.

Comment: I actually tried `node.next.value == targetNode` (targetNode is a value and not an object), but that didn't work for me, as I was getting an error that `node.next.value` is not defined (which was weird to me...)...I know that `node.next` and `node.value`  are valid, but for some reason `node.next.value` was throwing an error...I know I'm so close and I'd love to understand why it's not working :)

Comment: I had thought the same thing but your answer gives me the following error:

`if node.next.value == targetNode:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: Could you show how you call your function? if `targetNode` is a value and not a node then your naming is a bit unclear. Also if you values as target for you insert before then you will only be able to insert befor the first occurrence of that value in your list.

Comment: I've added the solution that I was able to figure out below, I call my insertBefore() function as follows: 

`names = SinglyLinkedList()`
`names.insertBefore('Tim','John')` 
(this is for a linked list where I'm wishing to insert 'John' before the node 'Tim'.) 

`targetNode` is a value, perhaps targetValue would be more appropriate.

Comment: Okay, I have now updated the code, so that it uses the value of the nodes instead of the actual node. Your solution still have the problem that it does not check if the head of the list is the target node, thus you are unable to insert a node in the beginning of the list.
Again, I want to say that `insertBefore` is only well defined as long as your list do not contain any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution of your problem.

```
def addBefore(self, nextData, data):
    newNode = Node(data, None)

    if self.head.data == nextData:
        newNode.next = self.head
        self.head = newNode
        return

    ptr = self.head
    while ptr is not None:
        if ptr.data == nextData:
            newNode.next = ptr
            parPtr.next = newNode
            break
        else:
            parPtr = ptr
            ptr = ptr.next
```